# Getting Saved cursor position 2/2 out of range for (restored) text error in android?

Tags: android, textview, cursor-position

Can any body help me what is the problem i am facing. My application works fine, But some time it will show FORCE CLOSE exception.

I find error in logcat as.

```
10-14 11:01:50.484: ERROR/TextView(987): Saved cursor position 2/2 out of range for (restored) text
```

Comment: are doing any DB operations in background thread or service?

Comment: yes. I am passing values from on activity to another.

Comment: what mechanism you r using to pass values from one activity to another activity.

Answer (score 2):

This message is actually generate by code in the TextView class method onRestoreInstanceState().  Somewhere in your code you are saving the state of a TextView then restoring it.  Look for some TextView, or an instance of something derived from TextView.  That is where you are getting this message.

Comment: Ok agreed problem is textview. But you never mentioned how to remove that or what the cause, I mean why text view is giving such a problem

Comment: I get this error from a TimePicker in a tabbed fragment, when the fragment view is destroyed and recreated (e.g. tabbing away and back). This happens even though neither the host activity or the fragment itself are stopped or recreated. Resetting the hour and minute in onCreateView has no effect, and I don't know how to access the TextViews within the TimePicker to do anything with the cursors.

Comment: @stonefury: I also met same problem. The only solution I know is you have to specify `android:configChanges="orientation"` inside the `<activity>` in your application's AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I also met same problem. The only solution I know is you have to specify `android:configChanges="orientation"` inside the `<activity>` in your application's AndroidManifest.xml.

Reference: [Changing orientation clears the TimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753938/changing-orientation-clears-the-timepicker)